# ROS with Chrono Engine

Tags: ros, gazebo, bullet, physics, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I was shopping for a physics engine that did, well, everything, and everybody pointed me toward Chrono.

It certainly does seem to fit the bill.  Of course, not everybody is like me and wants to do molecular dynamics in the same space being used to represent your robot's CRAM belief state, but hey, it's the 21st century.

Is anybody (besides this guy: https://github.com/amelmquist/Chrono_Gazebo) interfacing ROS with Chrono?

-Todd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226354/ros-with-chrono-engine/) by [toddcpierce](https://answers.ros.org/users/25497/toddcpierce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-04**:
It looks like that repo has been taken down but a few forks live on, https://github.com/huckl3b3rry87/Chrono_Gazebo/ has what look to be the latest commits from the original

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-10-04**:
https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/issues/1107 indicates that autoware has chrono integration, but unless someone were already using autoware disentangling it to use standalone seems intimidating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Chrono/Gazebo project that you linked is probably your best bet, combined with gazebo_ros_pkgs. Asher (author of that repo) is a grad student at the lab at University of Wisconsin Madison that founded Chrono. I haven't heard of other efforts that bridge Chrono and ROS without Gazebo.

And yes, you might want to invest in a supercomputer if you are planning on doing navigation and motion planning while running Chrono with a real-time factor of 1 :)

---

Originally posted by [jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/23055/jackie/) with karma: 296 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0